# How get errors in form html using passport local

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, passport-local

Thanks in advance . I am trying to develop a simple logging with passport-local. I'm using Node, Express and Vue.js(SPA) http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/.
When the loggin is correct, the flow is also correct, I receive the cookie in my browser and I m redirecto to *home*. But my problem is when the username and password are incorrect, I cant get the message error, only my app is redirected to the *failureRedirect*.
For example , I would like show the errors when the password is incorrect.
This is my code.

**login.html**

```
<form action="/auth/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <! -- show here my error -->
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

**auth.router.js**

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home',
                                 failureRedirect: '/signin'
                                  })
);
```

**passport.service**

```
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        {   usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
        },
        function (username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({ where: { email: username } })
                .then(function (users) {
                    if (!users) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
                    }
                    if (users.password !== password) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    }
                    return done(null, users);
                })
                .catch(err => done(err));
        }
    ));
```

**server.js**

```
require('./services/passport');
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '8mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '8mb', extended: false }));
app.use(
    cookieSession({
      maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000,
      keys: [config.cookieKey]
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I want to show in the form the errors *'Incorrect email.'* or 'Incorrect password.'.

Comment: Hey, you should really consider using ajax if you want to handle incorrect password or username thing. Just alert the user if password is wrong. Otherwise, just open the profile page. But remember that redirecting on server side won't work if you have made an ajax request.

Comment: thanks @VipulTyagi, but in this case , is it possible get the cookie session ?

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure about that. You should try doing this on a sample project. Anyway, server will always send the cookie in response